# MIFARE Classic standard keys

Tags: authentication, nfc, rfid, mifare, ndef

I have two NFC tags with different keys for their sectors:

- Tag 1: This tag contains an NDEF message.

  - Sector 0 = `A0:A1:A2:A3:A4:A5` for key A
  - Sector 1 to 15 = `D3:F7:D3:F7:D3:F7` for key A
- Tag 2: No NDEF data on this tag

  - All sectors = `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` for key A and B

Are there standard keys for MIFARE Classic tags according NDEF/non-NDEF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.

The application note [*MIFARE Classic as NFC Type MIFARE Classic Tag*](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1305.pdf) defines how a MIFARE Classic tag can be used to store NDEF data. This application note defines that all sectors containing NDEF data must be readable with a key A with the value `D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7`. Consequently, all data sectors (sector >= 1) are reable with key A = `D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7`.

Moreover, the tag must contain a MIFARE application directory where the data sectors are marked as containing the NDEF application. The application note [*MIFARE Application Directory (MAD)*](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10787.pdf) defines the structure of the MAD and it also requires that the MAD sector(s) are readable with a key A with the value `A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5`. Consequently, the MAD sector (sector 0) is reable with key A = `A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5`.

Finally, the default transport configuration for MIFARE Classic tags (i.e. when they ship from factory) is all sectors readble and writable with key A = `FF FF FF FF FF FF`.